# HelloWorld на PHP

Tags: php

Почему этот код вместо foo выводит следующие две строки (вот даже тут):

```
<html>
    <body>
        <?php
           echo "<p>foo</p>";
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

PHP впервые вижу, а пример - копипаст с википедии.

```
<html>
<body>
    <?php
       echo "<p>foo</p>";
    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Тэги удалены, остаток - это. Для запуска `PHP` нужен интерпретатор как бы.

Comment: А какое файловое расширение у вашего файла?

Comment: "Даже тут" выводится неправильно, потому что вставленный вами кусок кода не был должным образом отформатирован в формате markdown. Для этого в редакторе есть кнопка `{}`

Comment: Денвер я ставил. И в index.html это вносил. Нужно что-то еще поставить?

Comment: Файл должен быть *.php формата и должен быть размещен на php сервере

Comment: `> php yourfile_name.ext`

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.webserver.php

Answer (score 1):

Потому что php это серверный язык. Нужно сначала установить сервер на Ваш компьютер и потом открывать ваши файлы которые размещены в спец папке сервера через браузер.

Почитайте про то как работает php и как установить локальный сервер, например [тут](http://simple-training.com/basics-of-php_xampp-in-win8-32.html) или [тут](http://ru.html.net/tutorials/php/lesson2b.php)

Comment: Не серверный а скриптовой(правда интерпритатор обычно на сервере)! Сервер необходим только для доступа из браузера. С версии 5.4 в ПХП сервер встроили.